# Identify mushroom found at the base of a red fir stump

Tags: identification, mushrooms

I found this mushroom at the base of a [red fir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abies_magnifica) stump at around 7000' (2100 m) above sea level. It is light brown with white markings.

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to know exactly where you saw it. Red fir is found through the Sierra Nevada and southern Cascades.

Comment: post another photo the other way around, so the gills beneath the cap and the top of the stalk are on display if you can please

Comment: Or even cut it in half and take a picture might be helpful also